# Jenkins fails: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input

Tags: shell, ubuntu, jenkins, sudo

While Jenkins building, it gives **an error** on console output like:

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

How can i fix this situation?

---

There is this command in Execute Shell in configure:

```
sudo pnpm run build
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)
```

Output:

```
16:42:03  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
16:42:03  > git checkout -f 9998780d6a154bab01b4c010616f25a6f018d80c # timeout=10
16:42:03 Commit message: "fix swr"
16:42:03  > git rev-list --no-walk 9998780d6a154bab01b4c010616f25a6f018d80c # timeout=10
16:42:04 [ProjectReact] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins14253074063433648143.sh
16:42:04 + sudo pnpm run build
16:42:04 sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
16:42:04 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
16:42:04 Finished: FAILURE
```

If i dont use "sudo" command at beginning of the pnpm command but i needed to use it for kill port and start again

Answer (score 2):

Remove `sudo` from your script and let `pnpm` run without it -- it doesn't require root permissions anyway.

`sudo` is meant to be used in the terminal by a human user, and by default it requires the user's password to run commands with elevated privileges.

When running jobs on Jenkins you shouldn't be using `sudo`.

Comment: but then it was saying that is not possible to create a file under .next/ folder. It was giving permission error. Fortunately, I found the solution by trying to serve the project in jenkins user. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I removed "sudo" beginning of the pnpm but i needed it to use for kill port and start again.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for the usage of sudo command in jenkins execute shell.

```
sudo su    
nano /etc/sudoers
```

add following line under the comment #User privilege specification.

```
jenkins ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL
```

After this, I could use "**sudo**" command in jenkins.

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution; Normally you don't want to manage processes - this is the operating system's job. The best approach would be to find out why the processes keep running in the first place so that they can end gracefully without needing to kill them.

Comment: This helped me a lot for a different issue but regarding sudo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this and it worked

1. Open a terminal and switch to the root user:

   sudo su
2. Add the Jenkins user to the `docker` group:

   usermod -aG docker jenkins
3. Exit the root shell:

   exit
4. Restart the Jenkins service:

   sudo service jenkins restart

By switching to the root user in the terminal, you should have the necessary privileges to add the Jenkins user to the `docker` group. After completing these steps, Jenkins should have the required permissions to access the Docker daemon.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

This answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.